# Which way to creating variable in typescript better

Tags: typescript, variables, constants, var, code-formatting

I have a class:

```
export class ICar {
  wheels: number;
  color: string;
  type: string;
}
```

And when I want to create a variable Which way to creating will be better?

First:

```
const car = {
  wheels: 4,
  color: 'red',
  type: 'truck'
} as ICar;
```

Or second:

```
var car = new ICar(); 
car.wheels = 4; 
car.color = 'red'; 
car.type = 'truck';
```

Comment: Define "better"... Also note that those do two different things; Personally, though, I'd prefer the `const` initializer whenever possible.

Comment: The second one doesn't even compile since an interface isn't a class, so that makes the choice easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ICar` is a class then the first example is most definitely *wrong.*

Expanding on your example, let's say you have this:

```
export class ICar {
    wheels: number;
    color: string;
    type: string;

    constructor() {
        this.wheels = 2;
        this.color = 'blue';
        this.type = 'motorcycle'
    }

    drive() {
        console.log('Driving!')
    }
}
```

The correct way to create an instance of a class is with the `new` keyword.

```
// Good
var car1 = new ICar(); 
car1.wheels = 4; 
car1.color = 'red'; 
car1.type = 'truck'; 
car1.drive() // Works
```

Note that last line. `car1.drive()` only exists because the class was instantiated.

If I do the same thing with a typecast:

```
// Very bad
const car2 = {
    wheels: 4,
    color: 'red',
    type: 'truck'
} as ICar;
car2.drive() // ! Runtime error !
```

Now `car2.drive()` raises a runtime error because the method doesn't exist. This is because `as ICar` doesn't actually *do* anything in your compiled code. The `as` keyword decalres that the developer knows better than the typescript compiler and to treat a value as a different type than it otherwise would have. It does *not* actually transform that value into something else. So it does not change this object literal into an instance of `ICar`.

So by using `as` here, you are actually creating a bug that typescript would have otherwise caught

[Playground with code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=32&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=77#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EkDCKpwDeAUHGXAO4AWwwSaAXHAHYCuAtgEbBQDcp5BBCTQmaGFACWzAOb9ycGAE8wwMROlziAskObiorBDGgAKAJREdCxVUloAdNVr04AXjgAmeTbIw7jkIiBB4A5JxIrMChPr7+9g7Kqu5woewQJlAISsjR1gC+2goAJlIAbsAWVr66EPrCwA4iMqahACLlmgCEoeYFxIXEAPRDcADiEBDFxGX4iPgAjCnMwBTYeFAWvHDECItONHSYHgAs27v7QdApoVDAxTE7e1ALiSrANxJGANaPFy8OUqSCpVEZwADq0G+aG0YIAajwlHBOChpnpxPMoJ4UiQFM4jkwTgAaaxXKBMW73UIkhRJNSpL4IX4DODodb4fjPTyA8qVSxgrpwABKrGYMEk7A+PCg1y6sNGACFUUTkax4HS0AgpGB4HsYAgaJh-FKoDKoLs6hjngBmJi4OYeQhwMF0uDS0RwAAKMtUsCRoSBFVCcHscHY9jQmhDzEU72s+PohJpgmEHspD2TfneFMZzPynPw1p5wL5ztGkNYSGKcAAZihJEgVZw1bHVJrtfAKHVdRB2GAGx8KJJ-LYPihOBAKm7TdAgA)

Answer (score 0):

If you [try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EkDCKpwDeAUHHAO4AWwwSaAXHAHYCuAtgEbBQDcpiEJNEZoYUAJZMA5nzIwAnmGAixkmcQC+xYgghNRifAEY4AXiL8qNOowAsAGn66hURgHIowACZvHcxcpwbmIsCADWbppw6Nh4vNoAbviGUABMZszA5LH4ABQAlDxwOvipAHRWtJjmtkUlaWXO0Bke3m51CKVlCkotIeHtcEA) in the TypeScript Playground, you'll find that your code doesn't even compile.

You may be looking for an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead of a `class`. An `interface` simply defines what kind of shape an object should have, while a `class` introduces `contructor()`, methods, and all sorts of things you probably don't need. Here's how I would write your example:

```js
// Define an interface specifying what a Car should look like
export interface ICar {
  wheels: number;
  color: string;
  type: string;
}

// Declare a variable implementing the ICar interface, 
// and assign to it a satisfactory object
const car1: ICar = {
  wheels: 4,
  color: 'red',
  type: 'truck'
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use second

```
var car = {}; 
car.wheels = 4; 
car.color = 'red'; 
car.type = 'truck';
```

The first object is declared by const. so It can't be changed later.
so It will be good to use the first choice

Comment: Hello.sorry for my fault. I fixed my code.Please check it.